# react fetch data from multiple apis with async await and hooks

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I am currently fetching data from one endpoint. I want to store another api endpoints data in a state variable in the onload function. However I am not to sure how to fetch multiple end points.

the second end point which I need to call:

```
'/api/get_all_test_types'
```

This shows the code used to fetch one end point

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoadCreateUnitTests() {
          
          const results = await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user)
    
          autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(results)
    
        }
    
        onLoadCreateUnitTests()
    
      }, [])
```

MarkCBall Code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoadCreateUnitTests() {

      const results = await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user)
      const resultsAllTestTypes = await get('/api/get_all_test_types')
      autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(results)
      setAllTestTypes(resultsAllTestTypes)
  

    }

    onLoadCreateUnitTests()

  }, [])
```

Error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const results = await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user)
const resultsAllTestTypes = await get('/api/get_all_test_types')
autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(results)
setAllTestTypes(resultsAllTestTypes)
```

Alternatively, you could run these two queries at the same time like so. This will complete as soon as the slower of the two queries completes.

```
const getPromises = [
    await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user),
    await get('/api/get_all_test_types')
]
const getResponses = Promise.all(getPromises)
autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(getResponses[0])
setAllTestTypes(getResponses[1])
```

You could get more sophisticated with callbacks to that you start populating your as soon as the first get comes back like so:

```
get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user).then(autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete)
get('/api/get_all_test_types').then(setAllTestTypes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the indepth! I am using the first section of your code, however I am getting a setAllTestTypes is not defined error? The code I have used is updated in my answer, maybe I have written it in correctly?

Comment: Oh ignore, me, I need state to store the test type data!

Comment: Understood!

You need to set up some some `state` for the value to live. I assume you are comfortable with react hooks. Try a line like
`const [allTestTypes, setAllTestTypes] = useState()` to create a place for that data to "live in"

You can then do something like 

<button onClick={()=>console.log(allTestTypes)}>click me</button>

to view what you have in that new piece of state you just created.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do multiple `await` inside one `async` function

```js
 async function onLoadCreateUnitTests() {
          
   const results = await get('get_tables_autocomplete/b', user.user);
   const allTestTypes = await get('/api/get_all_test_types', user.user);
    
   autoComplete.setTablesAutoComplete(results);

   setAllTestType(allTestTypes); // recommend you to have some state so you can set it here
    
 }
```